# Calling a function in a class of another program - Python

Tags: python, class, call, default

As the title says, how do you call a function in a class of another program?

Class.py

```
class Object:
     def __init__(self, mood):
         self.__mood = mood
     def set_mood(self, mood):
         self.__mood = mood
     def check_mood(self):
         if random.randint(1, 3) == 1:
             self.__mood = 'happy'
         elif random.randint(1, 3) == 2:
             self.__mood = 'hungry'
         elif random.randint(1, 3) == 3:
             self.__mood = 'sleepy'
    def get_mood(self):
        return self.__mood
```

Generator.py

```
from test import Object
import test

mood = 'happy'
ani = Object.test(mood)

print("This is your mood: " + get_mood())
```

Mood is set as a default value of "happy". I need that to change based on the random integer roll in test so that when mood is displayed, it isn't always displayed as "happy"

Comment: Can you be more clear ? can't you just use the check_mood method to change the mood ?

Comment: This code is very... inconsistent, to say the least.

Comment: What is `Object.test()`?

Comment: Where does `Object.test()` come from? What is `ani` used for? Why `check_mood` is never used? `get_mood()` should be invoked with an instance of `class Object`. I thought you might not understand the difference between static and member function of a class.

Comment: @Saicharan S M, that's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm guessing have the default value before the call doesn't help. So I changed this: `def __init__(self):
         self.__mood = 'happy'`
Now the default value is set, `check_mood(self)` should change the mood, but I don't know if it does, because when I print, I changed it to: `print("This is your mood: " mood.get_mood())`, but the mood still isn't changed

Answer (score 0):

You have to ***explicitly*** call `check_mood` to change the object's attribute. See code below.

```
from random import randint

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, mood):
        self.__mood = mood
        self.__selection = {
                            1:'happy',
                            2:'hungry',
                            3:'sleepy',
                            4:'angry',
                            5:'bored'
                            }

    def check_mood(self):
        m = randint(1,5)
        self.__mood = self.__selection[m]

    def get_mood(self):
        return self.__mood

mood = 'happy'

f = Foo(mood)
print 'This is your previous mood:', f.get_mood()

f.check_mood() # This rerolls the mood.
print 'This is your current mood:', f.get_mood()

# This is your previous mood: happy
# This is your current mood: bored
```

Otherwise, if you want it to change "behind-the-scenes", I suggest calling `check_mood` *inside* `get_mood` (or just get rid of `check_mood` entirely and put its code inside `get_mood`).

However, the way `get_mood` is defined makes it modify the original `self.__mood`, rendering the original passed-in argument as lost once you call `get_mood`.

Answer (score 0):

There are... a lot of problems with this.  Lets start with your `Object` class.  You probably don't want to name something `Object` - it is too similar to `object` the Python builtin, and doesn't provide any real information about what the class does.  Additionally, you probably don't want to call the instance variable `__mood` - this will invoke name mangling which is probably not something you want.  You probably don't even want the single underscore; that represents a "private" data member (and there isn't a clear reason why this should be private).  You don't need getter and setter functions in Python because you can access attributes directly, but if you do want finer grained control use a property instead.  Lastly, we don't need to keep redefining the random variable in your `check_mood` function - in fact it will probably introduce bugs.  Lets look at this alternate definition instead.

person.py

```
import random

class Person(object):
    _mood = None

    def __init__(self, mood):
        self.mood = mood

    @property
    def mood(self):
        return self._mood

    @mood.setter
    def mood(self, new_mood):
        self._mood = new_mood

    def check_mood(self):
        rand_mood = random.randint(1, 3)
        if rand_mood == 1:
            self.mood = 'happy'
        elif rand_mood == 2:
            self.mood = 'hungry'
        else:
            self.mood = 'sleepy'
```

That's a little better.  Lets look at your other file now.

```
from person import Person

myPerson = Person("happy")
print("This is your mood: ", myPerson.mood)
```

This should print out the mood of the `Person`.

In your code you don't ever create an instance of an `Object` - you just call some `test()` function on your `Object` class, not an instance of it.  Then when you called `get_mood()` it doesn't work because that is an instance function - it can only be called on instances of your `Object` class.